# Конвертация в вектор растрового изображения с низким разрешением

Tags: изображения, svg, vector, inkscape

Имеется картинка низкого разрешения 32*32px (пиксель-арт), которая при конвертации через *potrace*

```
convert input.png temp.pnm
potrace temp.pnm -s -o output.svg
```

или через *inkscape* (вроде он тоже использует potrace), дает примерно такой результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при конвертации сохранить пропорции исходной картинки и не сглаживать так сильно?

Comment: Нарисуйте желаемый результат. Или укажите что изображение результата должно совпадать один-в-один. это всётаки "граничный" случай, и правила сглаживания нужно очень чётко прописать.

Comment: @nick_n_a  если изображений несколько десятков? все перерисовывать? я знаю, что граничный случай, в доках не нашел рекомендаций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать разные настройки

```
potrace temp.pnm -s -t0 -u1 -o output.svg
```

Или отмасштабировать изображение в несколько раз:

```
convert input.png -scale 200% temp.pnm
potrace temp.pnm -s -o output.svg
```

Результаты с различными настройками:

[image: Результаты с различными настройками]

Comment: Спасибо! Вы меня натолкнули на мысль. Использовал -scale. Как понял из доков это вариация ресайза без блюра, что для чб изображения самое-то. Ниже набросал скрипт для пакетного преобразования файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразование в вектор происходит через масштабирование и конвертацию в промежуточный npm-файл.

Набросал скрипт для пакетного преобразования png-файлов (32*32px) в текущем каталоге в векторные изображения. Скрипт лекго можно доработать и расширить

```js
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.png
do
  filename="${file%.*}"
  convert "$file" -scale 600 "$filename.pnm"
  potrace "$filename.pnm" -s -o "$filename.svg"
  rm "$filename.pnm"
done
```